# como faço para clicar em um botão e remover a linha da tabela via javascript?

Tags: javascript

Oi, como faço para clicar em um botão e remover a linha da tabela via javascript? o máximo que conseguir foi remover uma célula.

HTML :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JAVASCRIPT:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

resultado quando clica o botão :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E ai, Caião. Beleza ? Evite colocar print de códigos, e sim, copie o código e o coloque. Isso as pessoas copiarem seu código e reproduzem para tentarem achar uma solução pra você.

Comment: Eu tento colocar, mas a página lê o html na mostra ele

Comment: Tem um ícone que fica ao lado do ícone de inserir imagem (do lado direito). Ali você deve inserir códigos HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Comment: Coloca o html de qualquer jeito que nós consertamos. Mas só para ficar sabendo o texto aqui é formatado com markdown.

Comment: O que é markdown ?

Comment: Entendi agora, muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: @Gambi https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function removerElemento(elementoClicado) {
  elementoClicado.closest("tr").remove();
}
```

```html
<table border="2" id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tr-cabecalho">
      <th>Nome do Produto</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
      <th>Qtd Estoque</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
      <th>Descontos</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr-corpo-1">
      <td>Avast</td>
      <td>Protetor Antivírus</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>R$ 30.00</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td nowrap>
        <button class="editar">Editar</button>
        <button class="apagar" onclick="removerElemento(event.target)">Apagar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-corpo-2">
      <td>Word</td>
      <td>Editor de Texto</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>R$ 250.00</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td nowrap>
        <button class="editar">Editar</button>
        <button class="apagar" onclick="removerElemento(event.target)">Apagar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

No código acima, no **HTML**, quando clicamos no elemento (botão), enviamos ele mesmo por parâmetro na função **removerElemento(parâmetro)**.

No **JavaScript**, recebemos esse esse elemento e no **closest()**, procuramos o seu ancestral mais próxima que seja uma **"tr"**.

Por fim, utilizamos o método **remove()** (nativo do JS) para remover essa **"tr"**.

**Referência do closest:** [Closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!! Irei testar

Comment: Nada, Caio. Qualquer coisa estamos ai. Se, após testar, a resposta for útil pra você, é só clicar no "V" ali para aceitar a resposta. Mas faça isso só se a resposta resolver o seu problema por completo. Qualquer dúvida, é só falar por aqui que eu edito a resposta. Que a força esteja conosco !

Comment: acabei de testar e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado GAMBI

Comment: gambi, você poderia me ajudar em outra coisa?

Comment: Claro, brother. Se eu tiver conhecimento. Manda ai.

Comment: acabei de falar contigo pelo outlook, não estou podendo fazer pergunta aqui.

Comment: Você tem o nome do meu melhor amigo. Todo Caio é gente boa. Fique à vontade.